# Pulling a value from checkbox with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to check to see if a checkbox is checked and then if checked pull that data into a hidden field in my form as the value for my form to post. Here is what I am working with.

```
### Update User Profile
if (@$_POST['savePrivacy']) {

// error checking

// update user
if (!$errorsAndAlerts) {
  $colsToValues = array();
  $colsToValues['show_contact']         = $_REQUEST['show_contact'];
  $colsToValues['test']         = $_REQUEST['test'];
  // ... add more form fields here by copying the above line!
  $colsToValues['updatedByUserNum'] = $CURRENT_USER['num'];
  $colsToValues['updatedDate=']     = 'NOW()';
  mysql_update(accountsTable(), $CURRENT_USER['num'], null, $colsToValues);

  // on success
  $errorsAndAlerts = "Thanks, we've updated your privacy settings!<br/>\n";

  redirectBrowserToURL('edit-profile.php');

 }
}

<form method="post" role="form" action="">
<input type="hidden"name="savePrivacy" value="1" />


<div class="checkbox">
<span class="checked">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="view"> Yes</label>
<input type="hidden" name="show_contact" value="0">
<script>
var state = window.jQuery("#view").prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
$('input[name="show_contact"]').val(state);
</script>
</span>
</div>

<input class="button btn green-haze" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

I would like to pull the value from the checked state into the hidden value. Help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
var state = window.jQuery("#view").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
$('input[name="show_contact"]').val(state);
```